# [Rust Enums]: How to get data value from mixed type enum in rust?

Tags: rust, enums

Hello I am new to rust and just exploring how to use enums. I have simple code which has enum.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Thing {
    Str(String),
    Boolean(bool)
}

fn run() -> Vec<Thing> {
    let mut output: Vec<Thing> = Vec::new();
    output.push(Thing::Str("Hello".to_string()));
    output.push(Thing::Boolean(true));
    return output
}

fn main() {

    let result = run();
    for i in result {
        println!("{:?}", i)
    }
}
```

when I run this code it works fine but I am getting output like this

```
Str("Hello")
Boolean(true)
```

How can I get the values like

```
"Hello"
true
```

so I can use this values for further processing like concat the string or something similar.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the `#[derive(Debug)]` macro, which automatically defines the Debug trait for your type. When calling `println!("{:?}", i)`. The `{:?}` is called a "print marker" and means "use the Debug trait for Debug formatting".

What you want to use is `Display` formatting, which requires a custom implementation of the `Display` trait.

First, implement `Display` for `Thing`:

```
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Display for Thing {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
           Thing::Str(s) => write!(f, "{}", s),
           Thing::Boolean(b) => write!(f, "{}", b),
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you should be able to call:

`println!("{}", i)`

Which will use the Display trait instead of the Debug trait.

The [Debug](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_debug.html) and [Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_display.html) examples from "Rust By Example" are good if you want to learn more about formatting traits.